# How to define a Rayleigh Prior in Pymc3?

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3, probability-density

I would like to define a Rayleigh prior to fit the observations distributed in the image below. The current attempt was as a Gamma distribution, but as you can see this is a poor representation.

Using Scipy's stats module, I fit a number of potential continuous PDFs and found the best fit through a KS test (Rayleigh).

Unfortunately, PYMC3 does not have a Rayleigh prior in its continuous PDF library.

I would be very grateful if someone could show me how to define this prior. Current code below:

```
N_SAMPLES = 30000

y = df.demand

with pm.Model() as demand_model:
    # Uninformed priors for unknown model parameters 
    mu = pm.Uniform('Mu', 4000, 8000)
    sigma = pm.Uniform('Sigma', 4000, 8000)
    # Define demand prior
    demand = pm.Gamma(
        'Demand', 
        mu=mu, 
        sigma=sigma, 
        observed=y
        )
    # Step size
    # step = pm.Metropolis()
    
    # Draw posterior samples
    demand_trace = pm.sample(N_SAMPLES, tune=3000, random_seed=SEED)
    prior = pm.sample_prior_predictive()
    posterior_predictive = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(demand_trace)
```

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: I hope this does not offend, but the methodology you describe sounds highly suspect. One should not use a fit to your data to pick a prior. Priors are decided upon based on thinking about the nature of the data (e.g., its domain, does it have order/autocorrelation, are there possible covariates that might induce mixtures). Bayesian inference is about being completely honest about what we do not know, so that we can all have an accurate understanding of the uncertainty involved. Choosing priors from data compromises that clarity and can lead to false confidence.

Comment: Not at all offended and thank you for the comment - I should have been clearer here. The choice of prior is based on what I know about the underlying data generating process - There are two distinct clusters of buyers who exhibit repeatable buying behaviour 70-80% of the time, however this can vary through time (stationarity is indeed a factor but I would like to visit that later). Rather than modelling this as a dirichlet process I would like to test a Rayleigh prior to understand if this can model this uncertainty. What is unknown is the parameters to this, hence using uniform priors?